# How do I add multiple images to my clothes mesh

Tags: mesh, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor, surface-deform

I am designing a formula one racing suit that has to deform since it will be on a human character. I want to add images of sponsors on to the suit whilst keeping the background color (red) on the suit at the same time. I want to have the images on top of the background color. I am looking to add ten to fifteen images. I don't know how to do this through uv mapping or texture painting. what would be the easiest method to do this? Help would be much appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: hello, you have a lot of tutorials about how to add a logo on a surface, example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jn1KrLsGUUQ

Comment: here are some newer tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJlIeWhJh5g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tvJUUWYmHY https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hqd1-DX7Go